# How to grab URL path after locale "us_en" in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, request

Im am new in Laravel and Im tryig to grab in the route, everything that comes after locale ("us_en/").

This my controler

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\SitePublic;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request,$account,$location) {

        dd($request->path());

        $loc=explode("_", $location);
        $locale = $loc[0];
        $lang= $loc[1]; 
        App::setLocale($lang);


        return view('homeProfPublic')->with(['account' => $account,'active' => 'home','lang'=>$lang,"locale"=>$locale]);  
    }

}
```

For now I am using $request->path() to grab everything in the route.

My Route map is like this

```
    mySite.com/userAccount                   =>User's home page with English as default language
    mySite.com/userAccount/us_sp             =>User's home page in Spanish 
    mySite.com/userAccount/us_sp/contact     =>User's contac page in Spanish
    ...
```

So the **$request->path()** could give me the full URL and I could use php explode to grab all after locale (if it is the case).

So my question is if is there some function or method already done in Laravel to solve this situation? If yes what is it?

Comment: No, there's not an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use $request
If you set the route properly: you can receive the parameters in your controller function

You can set either 3 routes to separate the logic in different functions or one with optional parameters

```
Route::get('/userAccount/{language?}/{method?}', 'YourController@index');
```

And then, in your controller specify default values for the parameters:

```
public function index($language=null, $method=null) {
    list($locale, $lang) = explode('_', $language);
    var_dump($locale);
    var_dump($lang);

    var_dump($method);
}
```

And your will get for the url /userAccount/us_sp/contact

> string 'us' (length=2)
>
> string 'sp' (length=2)
>
> string 'contact' (length=7)

**UPDATE** You can create a middleware and process all the urls from there

```
php artisan make:middleware ProcessLanguageRoutes
```

You need to register the middleware in the app/Http/Kernel.php file

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
       ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\ProcessLanguageMenu::class,
    ],
```

And then, you can process the data in the handle function checking the $request variable

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ($request) { // check something
        // do something
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Hi @buzkall, so, do I will need to test each part of the code any way? I put here only one part of the code. I have a big menu and sub menu.

Comment: You can create a Middleware and process all the routes from a single function. I've updated my answer to show you how